# Visualforce page(table) doesn't rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce

In the app I'm working on I have a Visualforce page with a few `pageBlocks` and other fancy stuff. In one of the `pageBlocks` I have a `pageBlockTable` with a few columns that get values from the controller.

What I should have: once I click a button, I want the table to refresh(rerender) to show the updated values.

However, this is not happening. After clicking a button, both buttons on that row become disabled(as they should), but rows don't update unless I refresh the whole page.

Visualforce code(many parts omitted to make reading easier)

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
        ...
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Deals" id="dealsBlock">
            <apex:outputPanel id="tableBlock">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!tableRows}" var="d">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Accept" disabled="{!d.buttonsAreDisabled}" action="{!d.acceptDeal}" reRender="dealsBlock"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Reject" disabled="{!d.buttonsAreDisabled}" action="{!d.rejectDeal}" reRender="dealsBlock"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!d.theStatus}" headerValue="Status"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!d.theDeal.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!d.theDeal.Valid_Through__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!d.theDeal.Available_Deals__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Debugging shows that methods are being called and executed and the records that they create are effectively being created and saved.

I also tried changing `reRender` values to both `theBlock` and `dealsBlock`, but nothing happens. Controller still does everything it should, buttons become disabled as they should, but other columns do not show updated values.

I also tried using `<apex:actionSupport>`, but then even methods in the controller didn't execute.

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
public class DealViewerController {
    public class aTableRow {
        public Deal__c theDeal { get; set; }
        public String theStatus { get; set; }
        public Boolean buttonsAreDisabled { get; set; }
        //other properties and constructor for inner class

        private void initDealAction(boolean isAccepted) {
            Deal_Action__c da = new Deal_Action__c();
            //some basic initialization of this object
            insert da;
        }

        public void rejectDeal() {
            initDealAction(false);
        }

        public void acceptDeal() {
            initDealAction(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong here. Would it be possible to share your controller function(s)?

Comment: Add a <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"> tag and serenader that as well. Could be there is an error happening in the controller that is not being displayed??? What if you rerender the tableBlock?

Comment: @FrankZ see edit please. But as I already mentioned, that `Deal_Action__c` is being created and saved properly

Comment: @Eric what sort of error? Everything what should happen is happening(except for updating the fields in the table). And if I rerender the `tableBlock` nothing happens. Does exactly same thing as with `dealsBlock`

Comment: Found it. I didn't update the property in `aTableRow` class, so I was still having old values. And they were changing after refresh because controller was loading new values.

Comment: @Novarg, how did you update the `TableRow`? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because you are not recalculating the tableRows.

You could check if the `tableRows` list is being repopulated after you are done with whatever you are doing in your action. Perhaps you are just populating the `tableRows` in the constructor.

Or you could also repopulated the `tableRows` in its getter. So that every time the getter is called, it fetches the latest values.